# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arccos(\frac{1-x²}{1+x²})}{\arcsin(x)}$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arccos(\frac{1-x²}{1+x²})}{\arcsin(x)}$$

I found this in a calculus book and I just can't seem to get it.

I see that if we substitute $x$ for $\tan(y)$, we get $2y$ in the numerator, but then what do we do with the $\arcsin(\tan(y))$ in the denominator?!

Comment: Btw, the answer is $2$ according to the book, and according to WolframAlpha, the both-sided limit does not exist, i.e., its $-2$ from below and $+2$ from above.

Comment: How about L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: Use $\arcsin x \approx x$ and now the limit is $2y/\tan y$..

Comment: @Taladris I tried, but didn't get the correct answer...

Comment: Could you share your work after applying $L'hopitals?$ I've edited the title for searchability

Comment: @Buraian I am not very comfortable with differentiating inverse trigonometric functions, and feel like I must have made a mistake there. Could you try please?

Comment: Denominator is not $\arcsin(y)$

Comment: If you share the working with mistake, we can know you really put in the effort and can give you 'personalized' help.

Comment: You could use the triangle rule to figure out how to write the arcsin(y) = arcsin(y/sqrt(1-y^2) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\arccos(\frac{1-x²}{1+x²})}{\arcsin(x)}\overbrace{=}^{\text{substituting }x=\tan y}\frac{2y}{\arcsin(\tan y)}=2\frac{y}{\tan y}\frac{\color{blue}{\tan y}}{\color{blue}{\arcsin(\tan y)}}$$

Since $x=\tan y\to0, y\to 0$ and the blue colored part $\to 1$ and $\frac{y}{\tan y}\to 1$.